# how easy is it to mess with Firefox Javascript interpreter?

Tags: javascript, firefox, open-source, interpreter

since Firefox is open source, in theory it should be possible for me to hack behavior of the interpreter. Let's say maybe I could build my own profiler, or introduce more fine grained restrictions on what javascript behavior I will and will not allow in the browser. Or something, whatever...

So how easy is this sort of thing in practice? Is this something that could be achieved through some sort of plugins? Or would I need to recompile the interpreter source? Or recompile the entire browser?

How big is the interpreter source anyway? Is it a hard thing to grok for somebody who has built toy compilers in college?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you restrict yourself to just the interpreter, then things are not too bad.  If you want to deal with the two JITs as well, then it's obviously more work.  In terms of codesize, looks like we're talking about 180k lines of code (headers and C++ files), not counting the regexp engine and the jits.

Understanding the interpreter is not that bad; for one thing there's a good bit of documentation at http://developer.mozilla.org and people on the `#jsapi` channel on `irc.mozilla.org` are usually happy to answer questions.

Something like a profiler you would probably need to hack the source for if you want to profile without perturbing the system too much.  For experiments in terms of supported features, you want to use https://mozillalabs.com/zaphod/ instead, I suspect.

Answer (score 2):

The Firefox JS engine is called SpiderMonkey. You can find information about it there:
http://www.mozilla.org/js/spidermonkey/

I haven't looked too much at it, but it's written in C, and appears accessible enough.